# бот на aiogram и api google sheets

Tags: python, aiogram, asyncio, google-sheets-api

Мне нужно, чтобы бот через какие-то промежутки времени добавлял к гугл таблице строку, но когда пытаюсь через asyncio.to_thread или threading вывести таймер в поток, выдается ошибка.

Запуск бота:

```
from sheets.statsworker import rec_sub_count_for_today


def run_shed():
    while True:
        rec_sub_count_for_today()
        time.sleep(600)


async def main():

    ...

    await asyncio.gather(dp.start_polling(), asyncio.to_thread(run_shed))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Работа с таблицей(тут всё как описано в документации гугла):

```
class GoogleSheet:
    SPREADSHEET_ID = 'myspreadsheetid'
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
    service = None

    def __init__(self):
        creds = None

        if os.path.exists('token.json'):
            creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', GoogleSheet.SCOPES)
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                    'credentials.json', GoogleSheet.SCOPES)
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
                token.write(creds.to_json())

        self.service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

    def append_range_values(self, range, values):
        body = {
            'values': values
        }
        result = self.service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=self.SPREADSHEET_ID, range=range,
                                                             valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED', body=body).execute()
        print('{0} cells updated.'.format(result.get('updates').get('updatedCells')))


def rec_sub_count_for_today():
    gs = GoogleSheet()
    range = 'Subs per day!A1:B1'
    values = [
        [str(date.today()), db_worker.select_subs_quan(date.today())]
    ]
    gs.append_range_values(range, values)
```

Код ошибки:

```
2022-01-29 23:06:33,048 - INFO - aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher - Start polling.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\tgcitybot\bot.py", line 53, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 641, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\user\tgcitybot\bot.py", line 49, in main
    await asyncio.gather(dp.start_polling(), asyncio.to_thread(run_shed))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\threads.py", line 25, in to_thread
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, func_call)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\tgcitybot\bot.py", line 28, in run_shed
    rec_sub_count_for_today()
  File "C:\Users\user\tgcitybot\sheets\statsworker.py", line 63, in rec_sub_count_for_today
    gs = GoogleSheet()
  File "C:\Users\user\tgcitybot\sheets\statsworker.py", line 32, in __init__
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
  File "C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\tgcitybot\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", line 201, in from_client_secrets_file
    with open(client_secrets_file, "r") as json_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'credentials.json'
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000008E84AE1480>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 745, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
2022-01-29 23:06:33,110 - ERROR - asyncio - Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x0000008E870021A0>
```

Когда запускаю скрипт для редактирования таблицы вне бота - всё нормально, "credentials.json" на месте. Почему так происходит?

Comment: Я не слишком шарю в этом, но разве можно в луп асинхронщины забрасывать синхронную функцию?
Мне в голову лезет только изменить run_shed на асинхронную и вместо time.sleep() сделать asyncio.sleep()

Comment: asyncio.to_thread в принципе делает то же самое, как я понял тут проблема в подключении к таблице или типа того

Answer (score 0):

У тебя тут не правильно указан путь к файлу, из-за этого обрывается loop

```
File "C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\tgcitybot\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", 
line 201, in from_client_secrets_file
    with open(client_secrets_file, "r") as json_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'credentials.json'
```